# Visual Studio Code broken highlighting with HEREDOC and single quotes

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, heredoc

When I use that squiggly heredoc Visual Studio Code messes up syntax highlighting if I put single or double quote somewhere in the string.

Code works find but everything below that heredoc is green.

Any way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you see this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/issues/110)? Is switching your IDE an option?

Comment: Didn't see issue on Github, thanks. I guess there is nothing that can be done. Need to wait for them to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, you can use the `%()` syntax, that is perfectly highlighted in VSCode. See https://commandercoriander.net/blog/2014/11/09/a-multiline-string-cheatsheet-for-ruby/

And use Rails.squish if needed: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-squish